# how to prove that a set is not bounded above?

Tags: infinity, upper-lower-bounds

I got stuck in proving that $A=\{yn:n\in\mathbb N,y\in(1,\infty)\}$ is not bounded above? (without of course using lim)?

Comment: Suppose $M$ was its upper bound. What can you do with that?

Comment: Well.... do you know how to show $(1,\infty)$ is not bounded above?  If $y\in (1,\infty)$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ then $ny \ge y$.

Comment: Assume bounded . Archimedean principle? Then?

Comment: If $a \in A$ then $a > 0$ and if $M \ge  a$ then $M > 0$ so $2M \in A$.  But $M < 2M$.  So $M$ can not be an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in A$ then $a = ny$ for some $n \ge 1$ and $y > 0$ so $a =ny>0$.

Suppose $M$ is an upper bound of $A$.  Then for any $a \in A$ we have $M \ge a > 0$ so $M$ is a positive real number.  So $M \in (0, \infty)$ and so $2M \in A$.  But $M < 2M$ so $M$ can *not* be an upper bound.